# PHP TEXT to Image using mysqli_fetch_row

Tags: php, database, image, mysqli, fetch

I have this idea:

```
  $query = "SELECT vidRoles FROM videoinformation";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            printf ("<img src=\"roles/%s.jpg\>", $row[0]);
        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
```

In one (each)**vidRole** field in database, I have all together divided with comma Name1,Name2,Name3.

How using this code which I showed before, take each field divided each field like:

**From** Name1,Name2,Name3 **to**:

 Name1

Name2

Name3

I mean separate variables.


Finally what I need using Name1,Name2,Name3 to:

```
<img src="roles/Name1.jpg>
<img src="roles/Name2.jpg>
<img src="roles/Name3.jpg>
```

Comment: thats why you don't save comma delimited values like this, instead of just normalling looping, them, you'll have added the trouble of exploding them

Comment: do you know another way how to do it ??? when for example I have 500 names?

Comment: try out dynamic's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I got you. Anyway if you have a single field with multiple values separated by commas then just do:

```
$query = "SELECT vidRoles FROM videoinformation";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $values = explode(',',$row[0]);
        foreach($values as $v)
           if (!empty($v))
               printf ("<img src=\"roles/%s.jpg\">", $v);
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Also you should consider to re-design your table such that a single row is equal to a single image

Comment: Inastead of <img src="roles/Name1.jpg>
<img src="roles/Name2.jpg>
<img src="roles/Name3.jpg>   I have:

Comment: <img src="roles/Name1.jpg>
<img src="roles/Name2.jpg>
<img src="roles/Name3.jpg>
<img src="roles/.jpg>
<img src="roles/.jpg>
<img src="roles/.jpg>

Comment: Edited, You can simply check whenever !empty($v)